# Is there any downloadable collection of websites' source code mainly HTML and CSS applied to it?

Tags: html

I am trying to train an AI model on styling HTML with CSS and lots of data would be useful rather than me trying to manually download specific websites using scripts/web crawlers.
Mainly looking for basic website functionality and styling, nothing too complex.
To be specific a collection with .html and .css(applying to that html via id or class name) would work best.

Comment: Any/all html github repo with the branch named “gh-pages”?

Comment: @philshem Could you please give a bit more detail to your approach ? I'm not quite sure how to find the repos in the first place... Is there a way to sort all existing repos by ones which have said "gh-pages" or would I have to find each project individually and just download its files?

Comment: the branch "gh-pages" is what is picked up by github and rendered as public websites https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site

An example of these repos/branches/pages is found with this query https://github.com/search?q=index.html+path%3Agh-pages+language%3AHTML&type=Code

Comment: if you do go with GitHub as a data source, you can use the public dataset on BigQuery instead of the API https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/github/github-repos?filter=solution-type:dataset

Comment: @philshem Thank you for the clarification, I see how I could use github pages now and it is a great start, I might just make a crawler to download all html and css files found in there. I had a look at BigQuery, but I'm not sure how to use it for getting those same files.

Comment: you may want to use the API instead of crawling: https://developer.github.com/v3/search/